# Getting content of function (Between curly braces)

Tags: java, regex

I have a class with "n" complex functions like this:

```
public class Foo {
    public String getSmt(String param, Foo foo) {
        try {
            if (smtIsTrue()) {
                Thread mThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // Here I do something
                    }
                }).start();
            } else if (other()) {
                if (isExisted()) {
                    execute();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            doSmt();
        }
    }


    public String otherGetSmt(String param, Foo foo) {
        try {
            if (smtIsTrue()) {
                Thread mThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // Here I do something
                    }
                }).start();
            } else if (other()) {
                if (isExisted()) {
                    execute();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            doSmt();
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to get content of two function by using **Regex**. Could you so me how?
I tried this

```
(public|protected|private|static|\s) +[\w\<\>\[\], ]+\s+(\w+) *\([^\)]*\) *(\{?|[^;]) .*\{((\s|.)*)\}
```

But I doesn't work fine.

Comment: Why is this tagged as JavaScript?

Comment: You basically need a parser to do this.  Regex doesn't work.

Comment: @markspace Just out of curiosity : how do you use parsers in Java ? Is there something in the standard library ?

Comment: @Dici what do you mean "how do you use parsers in Java"? There is no parser library in Java, but there are some parser generators that produce Java code out there. The most famous one is ANTLR.

Comment: @Jack Duong I don't quite understand your question. Is this like a text file and you try to get the information out? What sort of information are you trying to get out?

Comment: @Ali that was my question, I wanted to know about the available libraries. Thanks ;)

Comment: @Dici A tool such as ANTLR basically allows you to write a grammar and then build a parser from it and means to navigate the parse tree and get your information out. There are already different grammars available for ANTLR, check here: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4

Comment: @Ali that's nice, thanks a lot !

Comment: @Ali: Right. This is text file and I want to get the content out.

Comment: @JackDuong and get the whole content as a string out? or in a more structured way?

Comment: what's wrong with `(?s)\\{.*\\}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{(?:(?!\n{2,})[\s\S])*}
```

You can simply do this to get what you want.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/rU8yP6/14

Comment: It's really nice. I edited my question, Do you have any idea?

Comment: It works fine. But there are some cases don't work. Thank you so much.

Comment: I would like to get all function in Java file.

Answer (score 2):

Use this.  **[DEMO](http://www.regexr.com/3a56q)**

```
\{((\s*?.*?)*?)*\}
```

Comment: It didn't work in some case. But I edited my question, do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

`.` does not matches end line so it wont help.

try this: `[^{]*\{([^aa]*)\}`

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression will work:

```
.*\(.*\)\s*\{((\s|.)*)\}
```

You need to the get the second capturing group, i.e., `.*\(.*\)\s*\{((\s|.)*)\}`. However, the content will be string. If you want structured content, then you need to use a parser for Java. You can take a look at Java Compiler Tree API, or use a standalone parser generator to generate a Java parser.